# How can I redirect a page to previous url from new url that is opened using window.location.href on clicking exit button?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a code for button in html:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" (click)="openUrl()"> Open </button>
```

And in app.component.ts, the first page is https://example.com, I have below code:

```
openUrl(){
window.location.href = 'http://example.com/url';
}
```

I have exit button in http://example.com/url page. When they click on exit button, the url changes to http://example.com/url/exit. Then, it should redirect to the original page https://example.com after 15 seconds.

How to listen to url of exit button and redirect the page to original one. The issue here is I have already exited the original page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an iFrame and do something like this maybe.

```
function removeIFrame() {
  var frame = document.getElementById("iframe");
  frame.parentNode.removeChild(frame);
}

function updateIframe(loc) {
   var frame = document.getElementById("frame1");
   console.info(frame.contentWindow);
   if (frame.contentWindow.location == "example.com/exit") {
     removeIframe();
   }
}

 function showIframe() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("frameWrapper");
    ele.style.display = "block";
 }
```

---

```
<div style="display:none;" id="frameWrapper">
    <iframe id="frame1" src="example.com/url" onLoad="updateIframe();"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: But how do I listen to the exit url to use history.go(-1) @Brian?

Comment: @CodeVenture Are you able to modify the code on the exit page ?

Comment: No. But they will be under the same server. They are two different applications. For example, http://server01/app1 and http://server01/app2

Comment: @CodeVenture Maybe an iframe would work?  I updated my answer.

Comment: I am thinking the same. But where shall I use the iframe?

Comment: Because when I open iframe, I just want to open new url without any content from previous page. I have lots of div in the original html.

Comment: When I press the back button on the browser, it displays the iframe which was supposed to be removed

Comment: So, whatever button or link would normally go to the new page,  have that button instead call the showIframe() function in my answer.   When the new page goes to /exit URL, the iFrame should close automatically.  If you want to detect browser back button use .. `window.onhashchange = function() { removeIframe(); }`

Comment: I was wondering why there is error from this.contentWindow.location as undefined. In addition, I cannot find contentWindow for the iframe. For example, document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow does not exist in angular component.ts for contentWindow. @Brian

Comment: @CodeVenture I updated my answer.  Can you try that and let me know what the console is saying?

Comment: After typing console.info(frame.contentWindow), contentWindow is underlined with red and when hovering over displays 'Property contentWindow does not exist on type HTMLElement'. @Brian And after building, the same error. It is not in the property list when I looked by typing just frame. only.

Comment: @CodeVenture Turns out it's different in chrome and firefox but also doesn't work cross-domain.   So another solution must be found.   Hmmm...

Comment: I am stuck on this if you have any idea. It is not cross domain.

Comment: If you would be able to help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we use something like frames[0] or ... in order to retrieve iframe url?

Comment: Thank you @Brian. I was able to resolve it. I have updated your code.

Comment: @CodeVenture Sorry, I ended up falling asleep.  Glad you got it figured out.  What did you end up using?

Comment: I used frame.attributes["src"].nodeValue. @Brian

Comment: Interesting, I know that is supposed to not be accurate if user navigation occurs but maybe if it is a redirect it does ?   I'm going to have to read up on that.   Nice job figuring it out. @CodeVenture

Comment: Do you think it is not correct? But I am getting expected value. @Brian

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to open the second page in a new tab then you can use window.open:

```
let newTab = window.open("//www.google.com", "_blank"); setTimeout(() => { newTab.close()},15000);
```

Comment: No, @Adam. It should be on the same page with iframe or _self without displaying any content from original page.